# Find the highest year in a string

Tags: expl3, arrays, comparison, filter, regex

I would like to hide sections of my document according to their publication date.

This is how I define my section:

```
\primarySection
  {Data 1} 
  {Data 2}
  {Data 3}
  {Jan. 1930 - June 2023} % Dates
  {Data 4}
```

This command is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand*{\primarySection}[6][primary]{

  \def\dueyear{2018} % Value to be replaced.

  \ifnum\the\numexpr\year-5>\dueyear
    \secondarySection[primary]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}
  \else 
    \secondarySection[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}
  \fi
}
```

My goal is to replace the `dueyear` value of the `primarySection` command in order to get the most recent year of the string in the 4th parameter.

In my example above it's `Jan. 1930 - June 2023`. It does not always have this form, but it always contains at least one year of 4 digits, sometime two years.

To do this, I thought the necessary steps would be :

1. Extract all the 4-character numbers with this regular expression `[0-9]{4}` and insert them in an array.
2. Filter the list to keep only the largest value (using a bubble sort or an accumulator).
3. Define this value as the `dueyear` variable. In our example, it would be `2023`.

I've started working with the expl3 package, but as I don't know LaTeX very well, I'm having trouble getting the result I want...

For the moment I can only extract the values corresponding to the years but I don't know how to create an array with them and even less how to sort them and extract the largest value...

Here is my function for detecting and extracting years:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \NewDocumentCommand{\extractMostRecentDate}{m}{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_extract_once:nnN {([0-9]{4})} {#1} \l_uiy_result_seq
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_uiy_result_seq {#1 - ##1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

How can I modify this function so that it returns the largest year from the parameter I mentioned earlier?

So that I can call it in my `primarySection` function to set `dueyear` like that :

```
\def\dueyear{\extractMostRecentDate{#4}}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The year is extracted with the regular expression `[0-9]{4}`. With `\regex_extract_all:nnN` all matches are stored in the sequence `\l__Skay_dates_seq`. This sequence is used with `\seq_use:Nn` and a `,` between the items. Then `max` is computed within `\fp_eval:n`.

The result is assigned to the macro `\dueyear` using `\edef`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\newcommand{\dueyear}{}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__Skay_dates_seq
\NewDocumentCommand { \extractMostRecentDate } { m }
  {
    \regex_extract_all:nnN { [0-9]{4} } {#1} \l__Skay_dates_seq
    \edef \dueyear { \fp_eval:n { max ( \seq_use:Nn \l__Skay_dates_seq { , } ) } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\extractMostRecentDate{Jan. 1930 - June 2023}\dueyear;
\extractMostRecentDate{01/02/1934 - 05/06/1978}\dueyear
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a good solution for data saved  badly , but a better solution would be to clean the data a bit, perhaps when it is saved. Dates always best to save as YY-MM-DD  then they always sort better.

Comment: Thank you ! The function return the most recent date. But I can't assign it to the value.

```\def\dueyear{\extractMostRecentDate{#5}}```
```\typeout{Little test (#5) = \dueyear}```

The ```\dueyear``` variable does not contain the return value of the command, but the string : ```\extractMostRecentDate{Jan. 1930 - June 2023}```.

How do you assign the result to the variable?

Comment: @Skaÿ See updated answer. The result can be assigned to the macro `\dueyear` using `\edef`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with `expl3` all along.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\primarySection}{O{primary}mmmmm}
 {
  \__sky_year_extract:n { #5 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \c_sys_year_int - 5 > \l__sky_year_recent_int }
   % replace the two following branches
   { not~recent~year~(\int_use:N \l__sky_year_recent_int) }
   { recent~year~(\int_use:N \l__sky_year_recent_int) }
 }

\int_new:N \l__sky_year_recent_int
\seq_new:N \l__sky_year_all_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__sky_year_extract:n
 {
  \regex_extract_all:nnN { [0-9]{4} } { #1 } \l__sky_year_all_seq
  \seq_sort:Nn \l__sky_year_all_seq
   {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { ##1 } > { ##2 } { \sort_return_same: } { \sort_return_swapped: }
   }
  \int_set:Nn \l__sky_year_recent_int { \seq_item:Nn \l__sky_year_all_seq { 1 } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\primarySection
  {Data 1} 
  {Data 2}
  {Data 3}
  {Jan. 1930 - June 2023} % Dates
  {Data 4}

\primarySection
  {Data 1} 
  {Data 2}
  {Data 3}
  {Jan. 1930 - June 2001} % Dates
  {Data 4}

\end{document}
```

Since I can't make a sense out of your `\secondarySection` macro (you end up with exactly the same tokens in both cases), I replaced it with code that shows what branch is taken.

[image]